# What is the difference between these methods in class

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react and I can not understand the difference between these two methods in a class

```
doSomething=()=>{
   console.log("Something")
}
```

and

```
doSomething() {
   console.log("Something")
}
```

Both looks like they do the same thing

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this, https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#why-is-binding-necessary-at-all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once again this has been introduced in new ES7 syntax. You can read more about it here

https://www.reactnative.guide/6-conventions-and-code-style/6.4-es7-features.html

Basically in old ES6 we had to write classes and binding methods like this (copied from the documentation)

```
class SomeComponent extends Component {
  _incrementCounter() {
    this.setState({count: this.state.count+1})
  }
  constructor() {
    this._incrementCounter = this._incrementCounter.bind(this);
  }
  ...
}
```

In new ES7 you can simply use arrow function

```
class SomeComponent extends Component {
  _incrementCounter = () => {
    this.setState({count: this.state.count+1})
  }
  ...
}
```

It is up to you what you gonna use. Both ways are ok to use but as you can see ES7 syntax is much shorter and easier to read

Answer (score 0):

```
doSomething=()=>{
   console.log("Something")
}
```

The above one is using [fat arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). You can access `this` (the class instance) inside this function without binding.

The second one is just defining a function. You will not have access to `this` here. You cannot use `this` inside that function. To use `this` you need to bind  the function in constructor or in some other place

Eg;

```
this.doSomething = this.doSomething.bind(this);
```

More on [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) keyword

Answer (score 0):

This is not quite so React specific but it does have implications when passing these functions around to other contexts.

Classes in ES6 don't require binding to allow the use of this within their methods, for example the following is perfectly valid:

```js
class TestClass {
  constructor() {
    this.variable = 'a variable';
  }

  method() {
    console.log(this.variable)
  }  
}

const thing = new TestClass();
thing.method(); // will output 'a variable'
```

The reason you would specifically want to use an arrow function is so you can pass this function down to a component as a prop or use it as part of a button action. Once you have passed the method reference away it no longer has access to `this`.

```js
class TestComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    this.variable = 'a variable';
  }

  method() {
    console.log(this.variable)
  }

  render() {
    return <AnotherComponent method={this.method} />
  }
}
```

Calling `this.method` from inside `<AnotherComponent>` will produce an error. This is where the arrow function comes in.

```js
class TestComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    this.variable = 'a variable';
  }

  method = () => {
    console.log(this.variable)
  }

  render() {
    return <AnotherComponent method={this.method} />
  }
}
```

`method` now uses an arrow function and 'lexically binds' `this` which basically means it takes its `this` from its surrounding context, in this case the class (component) it has been defined in.